# Is there a way to lock the GPS status to ON, disabling the users to turn it OFF?

Tags: android, api, gps, enterprise, administration

We have to deploy in our company an application that implements a tracking service for our assets (fleet management) to track vehicles by GPS.

Is there a way to lock the GPS status ON, disabling the fact that users can turn it OFF on the device's settings ?

We searched on the device administration API, but no way to find something related on GPS!

Thanks a lot,
Wally.

Answer (score 0):

No. Think about it. Would you like that application X started to monitor on you?
Let's think your aplicattion is honest and asks the user to enable GPS, and doesn't allow to put it off until some command, that's fine, but what about malicious apps?
I, and I believe I speak for many people, wouldn't trust an operating system that gives that kind of power to unknown user apps.
It's a matter of security.